# cmake/ctest generate Test.xml (without rebuilding?) / could not load cache

Tags: cmake, ctest

I have a `cmake` based (C++) project which includes tests created via `add_test()`.
The build process is basically:

- cmake
- make all testsuite
- make test

This has worked well for some time.

**I am now trying to get my build to generate a `Test.xml` to be submitted as part of a pipeline build**. It is not working for this project.

Q1 Can I tell `cmake` that I want a `Test.xml` to be generated when it (make test) runs the tests?

Currently I believe that a `Test.xml` can only be created by running `ctest`.
Presumably ctest aggregates the test results whereas `cmake` just runs them blindly?
Can someone confirm or refute this?

So I am currently trying to run ctest using:

```
ctest -vv -debug --output-on-failure -T test
```

As this does create the `Test.xml` file I need.
I had to add `include(CTest)` & `include(Dart)` to fix "`could not find DartConfiguration.tcl`".

However, even if I have previously run "`make test`" which guarantees the build is up to date it still tries to build and I get:

```
Error: could not load cache
```

For tests that run a compiled test (script based tests work fine).
The command it is executing is:

```
/opt/cmake-3.18.1/bin/cmake "--build" "<projectDir>/test/<TestName>" --target "<test_exe>"
```

The `CMakeCache.txt` & `CMakeLists.txt` actually live in "`<projectDir>/cmake`" which is why the cache cannot be loaded.
The command should be:

```
/opt/cmake-3.18.1/bin/cmake "--build" "<projectDir>/cmake" --target "<test_exe>"
```

Q2 Is there some way to tell ctest it does not need to run cmake?

My suspicion is no. Does ctest have to invoke cmake to run the tests? Does it just monitor and aggregate the output?

If I look in DartConfiguration.tcl I have:

```
SourceDirectory: <projectDir/cmake
BuildDirectory: <projectDir/cmake
ConfigureCommand: "/opt/cmake-3.18.1/bin/cmake" "<projectDir/cmake"
MakeCommand: /opt/cmake-3.18.1/bin/cmake --build . --config "${CTEST_CONFIGURATION_TYPE}" -- -i
```

I am running ctest -T test rather than ctest -T build-and-test why is ctest trying to build at all?

I've tried setting [Ctest_build_command](https://www.mankier.com/7/cmake-variables#Variables_for_Ctest-Ctest_build_command) but it seems to have no effect on the DartConfiguration.tcl generated.

Some clarifications:

- ctest works for me for other projects which use out of source builds
- This one cannot yet use an out of source build without massive refactoring.
- The source root is actually "`<projectDir>`"
- The CMakeLists.txt lives in "`<projectDir>/cmake`"
- Program source code lives in "`<projectDir>/src`"
- Test scripts and code live in "`<projectDir>/test`"
- My build worked using:

  enable_testing()

I never previously had to use:

```
include(CTest)
include(Dart)
```

One or other of these creates the DartConfiguration.tcl which is just a list of "key: value" pairs. I think this is used when ctest is invoked directly which was not the case here.
I'm not entirely clear on why and what are they actually for despite reading [this](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/ctest/Testing-With-CTest?version_id=d523de26dec5420d27012a3795d127ced7446c6c).

Also posted on the cmake discourse channel - https://discourse.cmake.org/t/cmake-ctest-generate-test-xml-without-rebuilding-could-not-load-cache/2025

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had some pseudo tests used to build the test driver programs via cmake --build. These were explicitly and inexplicably using CMAKE_CURRENT_DIRECTORY instead of CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR. Oops.